# What resin is appropriate for construction of a gasoline/ethanol fuel tank

Tags: organic-chemistry, polymers

I am building a epoxy resin/glass reinforced plastic (epoxy/GRP) gasoline tank. The expected service life is 30 years.

I've read that epoxy is relatively resistant to gasoline (some better than others) but will suffer surface deterioration with ethanol additives. I've been told by industry reps that vinyl ester resins are superior to epoxies for chemical resistance.

But I can't find data sheets on retail-level available resins that would be good for this application. I've heard that underground storage tanks at gas stations are all GRP, so there must be a resin which is appropriate. Suggestions?

Comment: While this certainly involves chemistry I suspect this and the related question might be more appropriate for https://diy.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Or https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

Because of **liability** due to gasoline (petrol) storage hazards, e.g., fire, soil and groundwater contamination, etc., I'd suggest you use an **approved** storage container.

Each locale has its own gasoline storage requirements, such as [Canada](https://www.canada.ca/en/environment-climate-change/services/pollutants/storage-tanks-petroleum-allied-products/regulations.html), the [United States](https://www.epa.gov/ust/frequent-questions-about-underground-storage-tanks), the [United Kingdom](https://www.hse.gov.uk/fireandexplosion/petrol-storage-club-association.htm), and there may be other regulations within a region, such as the state of [Idaho](https://www.deq.idaho.gov/waste-management-and-remediation/storage-tanks/regulated-underground-storage-tanks/).

Not only are there regulations on  the container itself, but also on additions, such as an outer container, fire suppression, etc.

Consult the petrol storage container manufacturers' literature in your area to see what is acceptable practice, but don't roll your own.

Comment: This project is a fuel tank for a motorcycle. Since it is smaller than most jerry cans, I think I'll dodge the regulations and do what is reasonable.

Comment: 1. The question should have included that fact. 2. There are still structural, as well as chemical, requirements that need professional advice. Try https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/